# How do I uninstall Python 3.8.10? (Error Python-3.8.10-amd64.exe does not exist)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to uninstall Python 3.8.10 but am having issues because I messed up the uninstallation process by deleting the folders manually and not using the programs uninstall tool. I followed suggestions here, i.e. repairing python then running the uninstaller, but it won't let me repair. All that happens is that a new window redirects me to c:/Windows/System32 and asks me to open up python-3.8.10-amd64.exe only every time I hit open it tells me that python-3.8.10-amd64.exe does not exist.

I am at a brick wall here, and any help for how to continue would be greatly appreciated.